# Can't change stringValue from label in Document class (Document based application, Mac)

Tags: arrays, macos, class, cocoa, document-based

I'm creating a 'test' document based application to learn more about how they work. I want to load an array that I saved earlier.

```
- (BOOL)readFromData:(NSData *)data ofType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError
{
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSArray *array = [string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];

    documentTitle.stringValue = [array objectAtIndex:0];

    // For testing
    NSLog(@"%@", array);
}
```

I loaded the file and got the data. I converted the data into an NSString. The file has multiple lines and every line has its own value. The first line is the document title. So I created an NSArray that put every line separately in the array. Then I set the first line of the document to the documentTitle label.  For testing purposes I created an NSLog function too. It has to log the array. 
 The problem is that when I run the code, it doesn't do anything at all. The documentTitle.stringValue doesn't change. But the strange thing is that it does log the array:

```
2015-09-22 16:57:40.098 DocBased Test[10765:277445] 
(
    "The awesome title!",
    "This is a document!"
)
```

I declared the documentTitle in the **Document.h** like this:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

    @interface Document : NSDocument
    {
        IBOutlet NSTextField *documentTitle;
    }

@end
```

If you need to view the project in Xcode here's a link: [The link](https://www.mediafire.com/?4z8d005q2wz0ici).

Does anyone know how to change the stringValue of the documentTitle (or any) label in the **Document** class?

Comment: Could you set a breakpoint at the line with: `documentTitle.stringValue` and ensure that `documentTitle` is referencing an object and not `nil`?

Comment: @A O You're right. The **documentTitle** object is nil. Can you tell me why? I've never seen this before.

Comment: Ah perfect, easy solution then.  Could you post the line where you are declaring `@property documentTitle`?  Is it an `IBOutlet`?

Comment: `IBOutlet NSTextField *documentTitle; `

Comment: I edited the question with that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your project @ https://www.mediafire.com/?z6drw20suvt0re0,
I was able to get it working.  Writing a new answer because my original is already really bulky, and fits more of a general case; whereas this answer will be very specific with your code

Only a few changes:
1) Because your Document.xib's owner is `Document`, you do not need to drag in the Document Object into your Document Outline.  So I deleted that.
2) I selected the File's Owner (Document), and set up the connection to your NSTextField property
3) I removed the ivar

```
@interface Document : NSDocument
{
    IBOutlet NSTextField *documentTitle;
}
```

so your header now looks like this:

```
@interface Document : NSDocument

@end
```

4) I created the property inside of your implementation file (Document.m) as well as an `NSString` property (I will explain that in a second)

```
@property NSString *titleString;
@property IBOutlet NSTextField *documentTitle;
```

5) So if you go ahead and override the `-awakeFromNib` method (Just put an `NSLog` or something in there), you will see that in fact `-awakeFromNib` is being called AFTER `-readFromData`.  Now remember what I said-- that the object is instantiated, but no connections are made until the view is loaded and the `-awakeFromNib` message is sent.

So what happens is this:

- You click "Open" and select a file
- Your `Document` is instantiated
- `-readData...` is called immediately during instantiation, but the connection to the `NSTextField` isn't made yet, so it's `nil`
- `-awakeFromNib` is called, and the connections from `Document` to any `NSView`s (including your `NSTextField`) are made
- but it's too late.

So the solution is simple,
in the `-readData` method, instead of setting your `NSTextField`'s `stringValue`, you should just save the string you read into a `NSString` property (What I mentioned earlier)

Then when your `-awakeFromNib` is called, you can just access that `NSString` property for the value you want, and set the `stringValue` then.

Here are the two methods that were changed:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib
{
   if( self.titleString )
   {
      [self.documentTitle setStringValue:self.titleString];
   }
}

- (BOOL)readFromData:(NSData *)data ofType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError {
    // Insert code here to read your document from the given data of the specified type. If outError != NULL, ensure that you create and set an appropriate error when returning NO.
    // You can also choose to override -readFromFileWrapper:ofType:error: or -readFromURL:ofType:error: instead.
    // If you override either of these, you should also override -isEntireFileLoaded to return NO if the contents are lazily loaded.

    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSArray *array = [string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];

    NSLog(@"\r%@", array);


    self.titleString = [array objectAtIndex:1];

    return YES;
}
```

Let me know if you would like more explanation anywhere, but this will work for you :)

Comment: Can you upload it to a file share website so I can download it (if it doesn't waste your time)? And thank you for finding a solution. I've been struggling over it for half a year now so it's good to know how it's done. I appreciate it.

Comment: Sure, here you go: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0lj1i1ezmv0u9ix/theTestApp%202.zip?dl=0

But I'd recommend you read my answer over and try to get it working for yourself-- it really isn't too bad any it'll help if you understand the underlying reason why it wasn't working

Comment: Okay, I'll do. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Luckily this is a common problem :)

Identify the .xib file that contains your `NSTextView`.  Say for example it's called `MyViewController.xib`.

In the Interface Builder, open the Utilities panel (the right panel, the button is in the top-right).  In the bottom of the utilities panel, click on the icon of the circle w/ a square in it, and search for "Object"

[image]

Now click and drag that `Object` into the left side (The Document Outline), below the "Placeholders" section.

[image]

This will create a new section called "Objects".

Click on your new object in the Document Outline.
Now back in the Utilities panel, go to the "Identity Inspector"

Change the "Class" to be `Document`

[image]

Now go to the "Connections Inspector" also in the Utilities panel.
Your (IB)outlets for `Document` should appear here, they'll look something like this:
[image]

Except instead of "nextKeyView" you will see `documentTitle`

Click and drag on the circle to the right of the outlet, and let go on top of your `NSTextField` that you want to be your `documentTitle`.

Now let's talk about what's going to happen.

- First you will instantiate your `MyViewController` with a method like
  `initWithNibName:...`
- Note that the `nib` that is backing the `MyViewController.xib` will not be loaded yet (this is called lazy loading)
- When you try to access the `view` property of your `NSViewController`, it will load the nib associated with it
- The nib is loaded, the objects inside of it are all instantiated
- The `init` methods are all called on each of these objects
- Outlet connections are now made, including your connection to your `Document` object to your `NSTextView`
- `-awakeFromNib` is sent to all objects that were instantiated through the nib

At this point, your property `documentTitle` is now referencing a valid  `NSTextField` object, and is no longer `nil`.  You can now set
   it's `stringValue` as you please

Hope this helps!

Comment: @A O Unfortunately, it's still nil. I noticed when you did it the outlet in the Connection Inspector shows under `Referencing Outlets`. Mine shows under `Outlets`. Can that be the issue? And I'm using Xcode 7 (beta 5) and I'm not using OS X storyboards (maybe that's useful). If that's not it, it's my Xcode again. I've been experiencing weird errors with it. I often watch tutorials on YouTube that are correct but the code just doesn't work when I try it.

Comment: No sorry, I was too lazy to create a new project but it should be in the `outlets`.  Would you like to just upload your project to dropbox or something, and I can take a look?

Comment: I uploaded it to MediaFire. The download link is: [https://www.mediafire.com/?z6drw20suvt0re0](https://www.mediafire.com/?z6drw20suvt0re0). It's a safe download of course. MediaFire didn't let me upload folders so it's a .zipx file. You can open it with the app iZip (free from the AppStore). I also put in a test file for my application to load. And thank you for your interest in this question. I'm really grateful.

Comment: Could you just right click the project folder and select "Compress *projectfoldername*"?  This will put it into a xib-- I'd just rather not download an app.  And not a problem, it helps me learn when I try to explain things :)

Comment: [Here's the link](https://www.mediafire.com/?4z8d005q2wz0ici). I didn't even know you could compress a folder. Great shortcut.

Comment: [And here's a test document](https://www.mediafire.com/?w9687w2ztzynnt2). I forgot to upload that.